# Hypergraph with networkx

Tags: python, nodes, networkx, hypergraph

is anyone familiar with networkx?

I try to get a hypergraph, where i want to set the Hyperedges as other colored nodes (size dependent on their value) out of an list. And i want to set the Nodes out of an other list.
The documentation and examples on the networkx website are really spare, but i am sure it is possible.

I started with [this example](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/stable/auto_examples/drawing/plot_weighted_graph.html#sphx-glr-auto-examples-drawing-plot-weighted-graph-py), but this is only an example for different edges. Can someone tell me how i can put up two different set of nodes with different color/size in networkx?

Answer (score 9):

Did you want something like this use `nx.draw_networkx_nodes` using `nodelist` parameter:

```
# Author: Aric Hagberg (hagberg@lanl.gov)
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import networkx as nx

G = nx.Graph()

G.add_edge('a', 'b', weight=0.6)
G.add_edge('a', 'c', weight=0.2)
G.add_edge('c', 'd', weight=0.1)
G.add_edge('c', 'e', weight=0.7)
G.add_edge('c', 'f', weight=0.9)
G.add_edge('a', 'd', weight=0.3)

elarge = [(u, v) for (u, v, d) in G.edges(data=True) if d['weight'] > 0.5]
esmall = [(u, v) for (u, v, d) in G.edges(data=True) if d['weight'] <= 0.5]

pos = nx.spring_layout(G)  # positions for all nodes

# nodes
nx.draw_networkx_nodes(G, pos, node_size=700, nodelist=['e','f','b'])
nx.draw_networkx_nodes(G, pos, node_size=1400, nodelist=['c','a','d'], node_color='blue')

# edges
nx.draw_networkx_edges(G, pos, edgelist=elarge,
                       width=6)
nx.draw_networkx_edges(G, pos, edgelist=esmall,
                       width=6, alpha=0.5, edge_color='b', style='dashed')

# labels
nx.draw_networkx_labels(G, pos, font_size=20, font_family='sans-serif')

plt.axis('off')
plt.show()
```

Output:

[image]

And changing labels and shapes too:

```
# Author: Aric Hagberg (hagberg@lanl.gov)
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import networkx as nx

G = nx.Graph()

G.add_edge('a', 'b', weight=0.6)
G.add_edge('a', 'c', weight=0.2)
G.add_edge('c', 'd', weight=0.1)
G.add_edge('c', 'e', weight=0.7)
G.add_edge('c', 'f', weight=0.9)
G.add_edge('a', 'd', weight=0.3)

elarge = [(u, v) for (u, v, d) in G.edges(data=True) if d['weight'] > 0.5]
esmall = [(u, v) for (u, v, d) in G.edges(data=True) if d['weight'] <= 0.5]

pos = nx.spring_layout(G)  # positions for all nodes

# nodes
nx.draw_networkx_nodes(G, pos, node_size=700, nodelist=['e','f','b'])
nx.draw_networkx_nodes(G, pos, node_size=1400, nodelist=['c','a','d'], 
                       node_color='blue', node_shape='^')

# edges
nx.draw_networkx_edges(G, pos, edgelist=elarge,
                       width=6)
nx.draw_networkx_edges(G, pos, edgelist=esmall,
                       width=6, alpha=0.5, edge_color='b', style='dashed')

# labels
nx.draw_networkx_labels(G, pos, font_size=20, font_family='sans-serif', 
                        labels={'f':'f','e':'e','b':'b'})
nx.draw_networkx_labels(G, pos, font_size=20, font_family='sans-serif', font_color='white',
                        labels={'d':'d','a':'a','c':'c'})

plt.axis('off')
plt.show()
```

Output:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The DisCoPy module is backed by formal research in DisCoCat. It uses NetworkX to implement hypergraphs. It also features a drawing module:

https://docs.discopy.org/en/main/_modules/discopy/hypergraph.html