# matplotlib to visualize linked lists and decisions trees

Tags: python, matplotlib, graph-theory

are there any tools or examples for how to visualize things like linked lists and decisions trees using matplotlib?

I ask because I wrote a linked list type of class (each node can have multiple inputs/outputs, and there's a class variable that stores node names), and want to visualize it. Unfortunately, my computer at work is locked down so much that I can't download other packages, so I've got to use whatever is on hand- which is matplotlib

I've started reading it, and if I do it by hand, I can probably make something that visualizes one-directional linked lists (just give it the root node, and plop down a square with text for each operation). But if there's branching, or multiple inputs into a node things get a bit more complicated- for example is it possible to expand a figure after creating it?

Comment: Yes, use networkx library and `draw_networkx`. https://stackoverflow.com/a/52683100/6361531 an example.

Comment: thanks @ScottBoston. If you add this as an answer, I will accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can use networkx library and the `draw_networkx` method.  There are plenty of examples on Stack Overflow.  Here is one example:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/52683100/6361531