# How can i determine the size of a node when I add it using the NETWORKX package?

Tags: python, networkx

My nodes in graph each have different sizes.
I need to determine their sizes when I add them in graph.
But using either `G.add_node('A',size=300)`or `G.add_node('A',node_size=300)`,
after `nx.draw('G')`
the size of A is unchanged at default size 100.

Comment: Look at using nx.draw_networkx_node...

Comment: I confront another problem when i try to use nx.draw_networkx_node.              
pos ={'A':(1,2)}
nx.draw_networkx_nodes(G,pos,nodelist=['A'],node_size=[300],with_label=True).And appear an error that is " Node 'A' has no position."I can't figure out why.

Comment: Take at look at this SO article.  It does alot of customization on drawing graphs.  Different size and shapes of nodes etc... https://stackoverflow.com/a/52683100/6361531