# Customise settings for edges and nodes using info from a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, networkx

Currently I have built a network using NetworkX from source-target dataframe:

```
import networkx as nx

G = nx.from_pandas_edgelist(df, source='Person1', target='Person2')
```

Dataset

```
    Person1            Age       Person2         Wedding
0   Adam John          3        Yao Ming         Green
1   Mary Abbey         5       Adam Lebron       Green
2   Samuel Bradley     24      Mary Lane         Orange
3   Lucas Barney       12      Julie Lime        Yellow
4   Christopher Rice   0.9     Matt Red          Green
```

I would like to set the size/weights of the links based on the `Age` column (i.e. age of marriage) and the colour of nodes as in the column `Wedding`.
I know that, if I wanted add an edge, I could set it as follows: `G.add_edge(Person1,Person2, size = 10)`; for applying different colours to nodes I should probably use the parameter `node_color=color_map`, where `color_map` should be the list of colours in the Wedding column (if I am right).

Can you please explain me how to apply these settings to my case?

Comment: Pass `edge_attr=['Age']` to `from_pandas_edgelist`?

Comment: thanks a lot, Quang Hoang. Would it be something similar for the node colour?

Comment: unfortunately I cannot see any changes to the edges :( I would like to have different size/weights (with labels whether possible, in order to see if it correctly assigns the length/size/weights)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC:

```
df = pd.read_clipboard(sep='\s\s+')

collist = df.drop('Age', axis=1).melt('Wedding')
collist

G = nx.from_pandas_edgelist(df, source='Person1', target='Person2', edge_attr='Age')

pos=nx.spring_layout(G)
nx.draw_networkx_nodes(G, pos, nodelist=collist['value'], node_color=collist['Wedding'])
nx.draw_networkx_edges(G, pos, width = [i['Age'] for i in dict(G.edges).values()])
```

Output:
[image]

Comment: Hi Scott Boston, I am trying to use this answer adding information on labels: `nx.draw_networkx_labels(G, pos, labels, font_size=16)` but it seems to be wrong. Labels should be from Person1. Could you please let me know if it is better to open a new question for this or if you could let me know here? many thanks

Comment: Yes.... you have to ensure the order of the nodes take a look at this post (https://stackoverflow.com/a/52683100/6361531).

Comment: Thanks you so much. It was very useful!

Comment: I have written a new post on an issue that I have had creating a graph. In case you want to have a look at it, please see here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66112129/graph-with-nodes-having-size-direction-and-colour-from-pandas-columns thanks a lot