# Network diagram with weight and type dependent nodes and edges

Tags: python, matplotlib, networkx

I have the following simplified database that I import from an .xlsx file

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({ 'from':['A','A','B','B','C','C'], 'to':['B', 'C','A','C,'A','B'],'weight':['10','5','25','2','4','8'],
                    'type':['typeA','typeA','typeB','typeB','typeC','typeC]})
```

Same database as above, presented for clarity:

```
from:   A     A      B     B     C     C       
to:     B     C      A     C     A     B      
weight: 10    5      25    15    2     4          
type:   typeA typeA typeB typeB typeC typeC
```

I would like to create a network chart that features

- Nodes

  - Different colour depending on the type
  - Increases size depending on weight e.g. Node A size is proportional to (10 +5)
- Edges

  - Different colour depending on the type
  - Increases width depending on single weight e.g. Edge AB width is proportional to 10, Edge AC width is proportional to 5

I have thus far been only able to produce the network chart that does not take into account this criteria

```py
G=nx.nx.from_pandas_edgelist(df, 'from', 'to', 'type', create_using=nx.Graph())
nx.draw(G, with_labels=True, node_size=1500, node_color="skyblue", pos=nx.fruchterman_reingold_layout(G))
```

How can I make the code dynamic and specify it to ensure that it meets the criteria as, say, new data is added or weights are changed?

Comment: This a little confusing, how you can you have Node A with different sizes?

Comment: What about the 4 on the "to" node A?  The weights are only attributed to the "from" nodes?

Comment: What about the size of Node D?  There is no from weight for Node D.

Comment: Yes, thank you very much! Indeed, instead of prolonging the example I will reduce it to only A,B and C.

Comment: See my solution below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a link to a [different example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52683100/6361531)

Here's your example:

```
import pandas as pd
import networkx as nx

df = pd.DataFrame({'from':['A','A','B','B','C','C'], 
                   'to':['B', 'C','A','C','A','B'],
                   'weight':['10','5','25','2','4','8'],
                   'type':['typeA','typeA','typeB','typeB','typeC','typeC']})

df['weight'] = df['weight'].astype(int)
nodeweight = (df.groupby('from')['weight'].sum()*10).to_dict()
G=nx.nx.from_pandas_edgelist(df, 'from', 'to', ['type', 'weight'], create_using=nx.Graph())
edgeweights = [i[2]['weight'] for  i in G.edges(data=True)]
nodelist = list(G.nodes)
edgelabels = {(i[0],i[1]):f'{i[0]}{i[1]}' for i in G.edges()}
nodesize = [nodeweight[i] for i in nodelist]
colorlist=[*'rbg']
pos = nx.fruchterman_reingold_layout(G)
nx.draw_networkx_nodes(G, pos, node_size=nodesize, node_color=colorlist, labels=True);
nx.draw_networkx_edges(G, pos, width=edgeweights);
nx.draw_networkx_labels(G, pos, font_size=10, font_family='sans-serif', font_color='white');
nx.draw_networkx_edge_labels(G,pos,edge_labels=edgelabels,font_color='red');
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: @user96e if this example helped you at all would you consider [accepting](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work?answertab=votes#tab-top).

Comment: This is very nice and I am able to replicate it with your code. One question on this part of the code:

nx.draw_networkx_nodes(G, pos, node_size=nodesize, node_color=colorlist, labels=True);

When I expand it to larger data with same structure, same unique number of origins in the "from" and those same unique destinations in "to"  I get an error on c :

'c' argument has 3 elements, which is not acceptable for use with 'x' with size 63, 'y' with size 63.

Comment: what does c relate to in this context?

Comment: This may be the colorlist paramater, you may need to create a dictionary of colors much like we did with edgelabels or a list of color the same length and order as your nodes.

Answer (score 0):

To obtain the graph from the pandas edgelist dynamically you may use pandas [`itertuples`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.itertuples.html).
Here's how it works essentially:

```
for row in df.itertuples():
    
    n = row[0]      # 'from' is a reserved word so 'row.from' returns Syntax Error
    u = row.to
    w = row.weight
    t = row.type
    
    G.add_node(n, weight = w, type_ = t)
    G.add_node(u, weight = w, type_ = t) 
    G.add_edge(n, u, weight = w, type_ = t) # weight of edge
```

Now let's add some prints to let you know when data has changed:

```
for row in df.itertuples():
    
    u = row[1]      # 'from' is a reserved word so 'row.from' returns Syntax Error
    v = row.to
    w = row.weight
    t = row.type
    
    if u in G:
        new_data = {'weight':w, 'type_':t}
        if G.nodes(data=True)[u] != new_data:
            print("Node {} data update: {} {}".format(u, G.nodes(data=True)[u], new_data))
            G.nodes()[u]["weight"] = w
            G.nodes()[u]["type_"] = t
    else:
        G.add_node(u, weight = w, type_ = t)
        
    if v in G:
        new_data = {'weight':w, 'type_':t}
        if G.nodes(data=True)[v] != new_data:
            print("Node {} data update: {} {}".format(v, G.nodes(data=True)[v], new_data))
            G.nodes()[v]["weight"] = w
            G.nodes()[v]["type_"] = t
              
    else:    
        G.add_node(v, weight = w, type_ = t) 
    
    G.add_edge(u, v, weight = w, type_ = t)
```

Now, drawing the network as you pretended:
Each type has a color:

```
type_to_color = {
    "typeA": "blue",
    "typeB": "red",
    "typeC": "green"
}
```

The nodes colors and weights can be obtained like this:

```
n_colors = [type_to_color[u[1]] for u in g.nodes(data="type_")] # u[1] must be either typeA, typeB, typeC
n_sizes = [int(u[1]) for u in g.nodes(data="weight")]   # you may want to scale these a little e.g  n_sizes = [int(u[1])*10 for u in g.nodes(data="weight")]
```

The edges colors and weights can be obtained like so:

```
edge_widths = [int(g[u][v]['weight']) for u,v in g.edges()]
edge_colors = [type_to_color[g[u][v]['type_']] for u,v in g.edges()]
```

Next, draw the network like so:

```
nx.draw(g, with_labels = True, node_color = n_colors, edge_color=edge_colors ,node_size=n_sizes, width=edge_widths)
```

#### *Here is the full code:*

```
def get_graph_from_pandas(df, v = False):
        
    
    G = nx.Graph() 
    
    for row in df.itertuples():
        
        u = row[1]      # 'from' is a reserved word so 'row.from' returns Syntax Error
        v = row.to
        w = row.weight
        t = row.type
        
        if u in G:
            new_data = {'weight':w, 'type_':t}
            if G.nodes(data=True)[u] != new_data:
                print("Node {} data update: {} {}".format(u, G.nodes(data=True)[u], new_data))
                G.nodes()[u]["weight"] = w
                G.nodes()[u]["type_"] = t
        else:
            G.add_node(u, weight = w, type_ = t)
            
        if v in G:
            new_data = {'weight':w, 'type_':t}
            if G.nodes(data=True)[v] != new_data:
                print("Node {} data update: {} {}".format(v, G.nodes(data=True)[v], new_data))
                G.nodes()[v]["weight"] = w
                G.nodes()[v]["type_"] = t
                  
        else:    
            G.add_node(v, weight = w, type_ = t) 
        
        G.add_edge(u, v, weight = w, type_ = t)
     
    return G
```

---

```
def draw_graph(g):
    type_to_color = {
        "typeA": "blue",
        "typeB": "red",
        "typeC": "green",
        None:"black"
    }
    
    print([u[1] for u in g.nodes(data="type_")])
    n_colors = [type_to_color[u[1]] for u in g.nodes(data="type_")] # u[1] must be either typeA, typeB, typeC
    n_sizes = [int(u[1]) for u in g.nodes(data="weight")] # you may want to scale these a little e.g  n_sizes = [int(u[1])*10 for u in g.nodes(data="weight")]
    
    print(n_sizes)
    
    
    edge_widths = [int(g[u][v]['weight']) for u,v in g.edges()] # you may want to scale these a little e.g  edge_widths = [int(g[u][v]['weight'])*0.1 for u,v in g.edges()]
    edge_colors = [type_to_color[g[u][v]['type_']] for u,v in g.edges()]
    
    
    nx.draw(g, with_labels = True, node_color = n_colors, edge_color=edge_colors ,node_size=n_sizes, width=edge_widths)
    
    return g
```

Any further questions, please leave a comment ;)