# Display node and edge attributes in interactive Networkx graph using Pyvis

Tags: python, networkx, pyvis

## Edit

I updated `pyvis` to version 0.3.2 and the plot is working as expected now.

Read on if you're interested in displaying node and edge attributes on a Pyvis visualization of a Networkx graph.

---

## Original question

I have two Pandas dataframes: `edges_df` and `nodes_df`. I used them to create networkx graph `G` which I'm then passing to a Pyvis network.

`edges_df` looks as follows:

|  | src | dst | color | title |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 140 | 1 | 3 | #379951 | T/B |
| 146 | 5 | 15 | #379951 | T/B |
| 7 | 1 | 2 | #0b03fc | 78 |
| 0 | 0 | 1 | #0b03fc | 62 |
| 139 | 4 | 10 | #379951 | T/B |

`nodes_df` looks as follows:

|  | id | color | title |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | #47abfc | I am node 1 |
| 15 | 15 | #47abfc | I am node 15 |
| 14 | 14 | #f24e77 | I am node 14 |
| 2 | 2 | #f24e77 | I am node 2 |
| 8 | 8 | #f24e77 | I am node 8 |

I created `G` as follows:

```py
# Declare nx graph from pandas edges
G = nx.from_pandas_edgelist(
    df=edges_df,
    source='src',
    target='dst',
    edge_attr=['color', 'title']
)

# Set node attributes from pandas
nx.set_node_attributes(
    G=G,
    values=nodes_df_renamed.set_index('id').to_dict('index')
)
```

The docs state that:

> Note that the Networkx node properties with the same names as those consumed by pyvis (e.g., title) are translated directly to the correspondingly-named pyvis node attributes.

Hence, I assumed that if my networkx graph had node attributes that follow pyvis' naming conventions, the resulting graph would automatically display each node's attributes.

However, when I build a pyvis `Network` from `G`, the resulting drawing does not display the colors or titles as expected. For example, I was expecting node 1 to be blue (#47abfc) and display the string `'I am node 1'` when the user hovers over it.

```py
# Imports
from pyvis import network as net
import networkx as nx
from IPython.display import HTML

# Declare pyvis graph from G
gpv = net.Network(notebook=True, cdn_resources='in_line')
gpv.from_nx(G)
gpv.save_graph('example.html')
HTML(filename='example.html')
```

Sadly, none of the `title` or `color` attributes from neither my edges or nodes is rendering as I expected.

[image]

How can I get Pyvis to render nodes and edges according to the corresponding attributes from my networkx graph?

The data I'm working with is HUGE (25B edges) and I'd like to avoid using for loops to add nodes or edges one by one.

---

## Summary

By creating a Networkx graph with node and edge attributes that follow Pyvis' [naming conventions](https://visjs.github.io/vis-network/docs/network/nodes.html), the resulting visualization will inherit the attributes of the Networkx graph.

For example, adding node attribute `title` will result in hover elements that display the corresponding node's title.

[image: success]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52683100/6361531

Comment: Thank you @ScottBoston. However, I really need the graph to be an interactive object that my client can click on. That's the reason I'm looking for a `pyvis` alternative.